# ArcGIS .Net GP tools debug

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, .net, visual-studio, background-geoprocessing

I'm developing a GP Tool with .Net ArcObjects SDK.

I would like to debug my GP tool but I haven't figured how.

I have tried to enable background processing in Geoprocessing Options and attach process to my Visual Studio but the GP tools crash with the ERROR 000820: The parameters need repair.

If I disable the background processing I can't debug anymore.

How do I debug GP tools developed in .Net ArcObjects?

Comment: Does it crash with background geoprocessing turned on, but without attaching visual studio?

Comment: It crash with background geoprocessing turned on and with visual studio attached. Workaround : Create a new solution, and code again ...

Comment: You can also start debugger in your code: `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()`